# Dispatch not working properly with Times

Tags: replacement

`Dispatch` seems to work incorrectly when the head of the lhs of the replacement rule is `Times`. In Mathematica 10.0 and 12.0 we have

```
expr = (x y)/2;
rule = x y -> 0;

expr /. rule
(* 0 *)

expr /. Dispatch[rule]
(* (x y)/2 *)
```

while Mathematica 6.0 gives

```
expr /. rule
(* 0 *)

expr /. Dispatch[rule]
(* 0 *)
```

The result in versions 10 and 12 contradicts the documentation's statement that "the use of Dispatch will never affect results that are obtained," so I'm guessing this is a bug. Unless I'm missing something?

Since `Association` doesn't help:

```
expr /. Association[rule]
(* (x y)/2 *)
```

I'm wondering if there is a workaround to allow fast replacements with long lists of rules of this type?

Comment: I can reproduce in 12.1 on Windows 8.1. Perhaps you should report to WRI.

Comment: Probably a bug, so I agree with @Edmund that it should be reported.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Will do.

Comment: Hi. Are there any news about this bug? Or maybe some workaround? Using HoldPattern inside Dispatch takes away all the time acceleration of Dispatch over sets of Rules

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that this helps clarify the issue, but `expr /. Dispatch[HoldPattern[x y] -> 0]` does return $0$. That might be a workaround.