# Not all rules being used in replacement

Tags: replacement, rule

Result I get for the following replacement doesn't seem to be correct.

```
    {a*b*c*d*e} /. {d -> d*f, a -> a*b*c, b*c -> b*c*d*e, c*f -> c*f*g}
    =>   {a b c d^2 e^2}
```

It didn't include `d -> d*f` & `c*f -> c*f*g`.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your replacement rules depend on the order in which they are applied. If you want a specific order you must use several `ReplaceAll` commands.

Using `Trace` you can convince yourself that MMA first applies the rule: `b*c -> b*c*d*e`. This gives: `{a b c d^2 e^2}. Why it then not replace e.g. `a` I can not explain.

Comment: @DanielHuber: Thanks for sharing your observation. I am also stuck on why all rules are not used.

Comment: Try applying one rule after the other.

Comment: @DanielHuber MMA's behavior shall match its documentation. Rules can be applied subsequently, but it looks more of a little trick.

Comment: Right, but then you have complete control about what is replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original expression there are no c*f so that rule does not get applied.
However if you use `ReplaceAll` it will create, in this case, an infinite recursive loop.
You can apply your rules sequentially by:
`{a*b*c*d*e} /. d -> d*f /. a -> a*b*c /. b*c -> b*c*d*e /. c*f -> c*f*g`

=> `{a b^2 c^2 d e f}`

Comment: Yes, but replace is not supposed to work this way that I have to apply every rule separately.

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate a bit on [Rudy Potter's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237759/42436) answer: Well one should keep in mind at least two things about multiplication in Mathematica using `Times`:

1. It is orderless and expressions get reordered according to Mathematica's internal expression sorting.
2. Times 'simplifies' to `Power` which is a complete nightmare when trying to replace parts of products.

Lets follow [Daniel Hubers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46318/daniel-huber) advice from the comments and apply the rules in sequence using `Fold`:

```
Fold[ReplaceAll, {a*b*c*d*e}, {d -> d*f, a -> a*b*c, b*c -> b*c*d*e,  c*f -> c*f*g}]
```

resulting in

> `{a b^2 c^2 d e f}`

Which is maybe not the result one would expect. Only the first two rules have an impact on the expression, since the third `b*c -> b*c*d*e` does not work on `b^2 c^2`
and the last will most likely never work on a product involving `e` and `d` since `c` and `f` will never be adjacent.  The potential looping problems might come in when using `ReplaceRepeated`. A further question is what even to do with `b^2 c^2`: use apply the rule to `b*c*b*c` twice? If twice to the first `b*c` or the second or one produced by the rule (here the looping would come into play if one where to use `ReplaceRepeated`).

The question/stated problem looks not very well posed to me and maybe using solve with a corresponding equation system to manipulate the expression might be a better idea. Switching (if only temporary) from `Times` to `List` to manipulate the sequence of terms in the product which would guarantee a predicable order of terms could also be an idea:

[image]

resulting in

> [image]

I would urge OP to rethink the problem/its formulation.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation, I know presenting problem in terms of list will get job done but I explored this on purpose.

Comment: Also, looks like MMA pattern matching doesn't know that multiplication is commutative, leaving much to programmer(a lot I mean). Also, replacing Head from Times to Power is quite uncomfortable. It reduces predictability of tool.
Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well Mathematica uses the commutative nature of multiplication to reorder expressions (which is necessary for simplifications) but it is not smart about it in a way a human could be. A human would reorder terms in product according to the situation but Mathematica does not try to use reordering to enable the application of rules (which might be very difficult to implement). But the fact that it has no explicit positive integer power function and that pattern matching like `a^4 /. a^2 -> 2` does not work out of the box is as you pointed out often very frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

Your question concerns the subtle pattern matching that occurs for [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) symbols, like [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times). When the replacement rule `b*c -> b*c*d*e` is encountered, any expression with head [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) is examined to see if the elements `b` and `c` are present, and if so, the whole [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) expression is modified accordingly. Since [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) works top down, the rule with [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) is used before the rules `d -> d * f` or `a -> a * b * c`. Once a portion of the expression is modified by a [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) replacement, that portion of the expression is inert to further modification by any of the replacement rules. So, the first rule that fires is the the `b*c -> b*c*d*e` rule acting on the complete `Times` expression, and then no other rules are used, leading to the output that you observe.

Comment: Not sure about the last part although the rest looks sound. If we change the rules using `Dispatch` then we get a couple of replacements. `In[449]:= rul = {d -> d*f, a -> a*b*c, b*c -> b*c*d*e, c*f -> c*f*g};
drul = Dispatch[rul];
a*b*c*d*e /. drul

Out[451]= a b^2 c^2 d e f` (`Trace` might show this more clearly.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Using Dispatch, the rules `b*c -> b*c*d*e` and `c*f` will only fire if they are literally in the input. Compare `a*b*c*d*e /. b*c->b*c*d*e` with `a*b*c*d*e /. Dispatch[b*c -> b*c*d*e]`

Comment: "Once a portion of the expression is modified by ReplaceAll, that portion of the expression is no longer modified by any replacement rules"...then won't it defeat the purpose of replacement?

Comment: @Sejwal My statement meant that ReplaceAll only replaces only once. Otherwise something like `d /. d->d*f` would lead to iteration errors since `d` is always present in the output.

Comment: @CarlWoll ok, I misunderstood.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if that might be a bug in `Dispatch`, perhaps in connection with `Orderless` heads.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: there is a bug with Dispatch in connection with Times already reported on redmine: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223744/dispatch-not-working-properly-with-times

Comment: @Philipp Thank you for pointing that out. I think my short-term memory should be taken out and shot...

Comment: @Daniel: no problem. Any chance getting that fixed for 12.3?

Comment: @Philipp I have no predictions re fixing that. My guess is it's not an easy thing to do.